# Restrict user from executing INSERT queries on athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I want to restrict user from executing INSERT queries in master table(Not CTAS table) in athena.
If there way, I can achieve this ?
user will executing queries from Lambda.

Comment: AWS Athena uses IAM policies to restrict access to Athena operations. Make sure you have appropriate permissions defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Athena just supports `StartQueryExecution` and `StopQueryExecution` as actions in [IAM permission policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonathena.html) - so there is no differentiation which type of SQL Command (DDL, DML) is being executed.

However, I think you can overcome this by denying permissions on `glue` and `S3` so Athena queries that try to execute INSERTs will fail:

- glue permissions can be managed on catalog, database and table level, some examples can be found in AWS' [Identity-Based Policies (IAM Policies) for Access Control for Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/using-identity-based-policies.html)
- Relevant glue actions to deny: `BatchCreatePartition`, `CreatePartition`, `UpdatePartition` - see [Actions, resources, and condition keys for AWS Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_awsglue.html#awsglue-actions-as-permissions)
- On `S3` you need to deny `PutObject` or `Put*` for the S3 location of the specific table, see [Actions defined by Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazons3.html) - again this can be defined on a object level in a bucket.